# Add a header to a REST WCF request - EnvelopeNone does not support adding Message Headers exception

Tags: wcf, rest, header

I'm trying to add a custom header to a wcf client hitting a standard, RESTful endpoint.  I am trying to add some kind of header that will just allow me to trace requests from one layer to the next.  Here's how I've tried to implement it:

```
public class DynatracePurePathHeaderAppender : IClientMessageInspector, IEndpointBehavior
 {
  object IClientMessageInspector.BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
  {
   var dynaHeader = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("Action", "ns.yellowbook.jeff", "dynatrace",false);
   request.Headers.Add(dynaHeader);
   return null;
  }

  void IClientMessageInspector.AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
  {
   return;
  }

  public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint){}

  public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters){}

  public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher){}

  public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
  {
   clientRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(this);
  }
 }

public class DynatracePurePathHeaderAppenderElement : BehaviorExtensionElement
 {
  protected override object CreateBehavior()
  {
   return new DynatracePurePathHeaderAppender();
  }

  public override Type BehaviorType
  {
   get { return typeof(DynatracePurePathHeaderAppender); }
  }
 }
```

I then configure the client successfully, but when this runs, I get the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Envelope Version 'EnvelopeNone
>   (http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/envelope/none)' does not
>   support adding Message Headers.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to insert this little barium meal?

Answer (score 5):

I assume you mean HTTP header and not a SOAP header? If so, MessageHeader has nothing to do with this.

Try something like this:

```
HttpRequestMessageProperty hrmp = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
//Set hrmp.Headers, then:
request.Properties.Add(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, hrmp);
```

In general, the WCF REST support is not really optimized on the client side (it was created mostly to allow people to *create* REST services). For much better client-side REST support, check out HttpClient in the WCF REST Starter Kit.

Answer (score 2):

In the method BeforeSendReply you need get Response:

```
var httpHeader = reply.Properties["httpResponse"] as HttpResponseMessageProperty;
```

When you have instance of response than you can easily add any header you want:

```
httpHeader.Headers.Add("my Custom Header", "My Value");
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late but I ran across this post so decided to fill this in, in case I ever need to remember this again. This worked for me:

1. Create the Message Inspector:

   ```
   Public Class AuthenticationHeader
     Implements IClientMessageInspector

   Private itsUser As String
   Private itsPass As String

   Public Sub New(ByVal user As String, ByVal pass As String)
       itsUser = user
       itsPass = pass
   End Sub

   Public Sub AfterReceiveReply(ByRef reply As Message, correlationState As Object) Implements IClientMessageInspector.AfterReceiveReply
       Console.WriteLine("Received the following reply: '{0}'", reply.ToString())
   End Sub

   Public Function BeforeSendRequest(ByRef request As Message, channel As IClientChannel) As Object Implements IClientMessageInspector.BeforeSendRequest
       Dim hrmp As HttpRequestMessageProperty = request.Properties("httpRequest")
       Dim encoded As String = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(itsUser + ":" + itsPass))
       hrmp.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded)
       Return request
     End Function
   End Class
   ```
2. Write the Behavior:

   ```
   Public Class AuthenticationHeaderBehavior
   Implements IEndpointBehavior

   Private ReadOnly itsUser As String
   Private ReadOnly itsPass As String

   Public Sub New(ByVal user As String, ByVal pass As String)
       MyBase.New()
       itsUser = user
       itsPass = pass
   End Sub

   Public Sub AddBindingParameters(endpoint As ServiceEndpoint, bindingParameters As BindingParameterCollection) Implements IEndpointBehavior.AddBindingParameters
   End Sub

   Public Sub ApplyClientBehavior(endpoint As ServiceEndpoint, clientRuntime As ClientRuntime) Implements IEndpointBehavior.ApplyClientBehavior
       clientRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(New AuthenticationHeader(itsUser, itsPass))
   End Sub

   Public Sub ApplyDispatchBehavior(endpoint As ServiceEndpoint, endpointDispatcher As EndpointDispatcher) Implements IEndpointBehavior.ApplyDispatchBehavior
   End Sub

   Public Sub Validate(endpoint As ServiceEndpoint) Implements IEndpointBehavior.Validate
   End Sub
   End Class
   ```
3. Add it to your endpoint:

   ```
     Dim binding As New WebHttpBinding(WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport)
     binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None

     ChlFactory = New WebChannelFactory(Of IMyServiceContract)(binding, New Uri(url))
     ChlFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(New WebHttpBehavior())
     ChlFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(New AuthenticationHeaderBehavior(user, pass))
     Channel = ChlFactory.CreateChannel()
   ```